# How to replace to_tsquery by phraseto_tsquery in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

For word suggestion when do search.

I can query like

```
select title from test where ts_filter(tsv, '{A}') @@ to_tsquery('english_nostop', 'god<->o' || ':*')

# tsv is something like to_tsvector('english_nostop', test.title)
```

The `<->` was something like `pattern = pattern.replace(' ', '<->')`. That may have some problem when pattern contain `<`.  Thought we can remove such char.

Combine tsquery don't work here. I can't find away to do `to_tsquery(':*')`

But how to use `phraseto_tsquery` to replace  `to_tsquery` ? And still can have `:*` work?

---

After @Laurenz Albe answer.  `phraseto_tsquery` can't do this.

May be I need give more detail. Why I want to use `phraseto_tsquery`.

I use the

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_stem_nostop (
    Template = snowball
    , Language = english
);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.english_nostop ( COPY = pg_catalog.english );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.english_nostop
ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, hword, hword_part, word WITH english_stem_nostop;
```

To keep stop words can be searched.

But I need to change pattern like this in python:

```
pattern = info["pattern"]
replace_punctuation = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))
pattern = pattern.translate(replace_punctuation)
replace_space = pattern.replace(" ", '<->')
```

You can see I replace `punctuation` by `' '`. Then replace `' '` with `<->`.

I came up this question. Because I wonder can I don't transform pattern in python and just use psql to transform pattern.

Why need both `':*'` and `<->`. here is a example:

```
select title from book where ts_filter(tsv_nostop, '{A}') @@ to_tsquery('english_nostop', 'how<->t'||':*')
except
select title from book where ts_filter(tsv_nostop, '{A}') @@ to_tsquery('english_nostop', 'how<->t');
```

This will show  title contain `how to`. When user input `how t`. We want pop up some title.

Comment: I think that using stemming but then adding :* doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Can you show complete examples of what you want to start with and what you want to end with?  What was the starting point that you want to lead to `'god' <-> 'o':*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with `phraseto_tsquery`.

The lower-level functions provide more features that you cannot get with `phraseto_tsquery` or `websearch_to_tsquery`.